# Slow PC with Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I've been having trouble with my computer since I installed Ubuntu 10.10 for the first time. At first it ran quickly and I was glad I installed it, but after some time I updated to 11.04 and newer versions and the computer began crashing. 
I've changed swappiness to 10%, removed the extra workspaces, purged it and switched to Gnome instead of Unity, but it's still slow.
I can't even watch Youtube videos, beacuse they make the computer freeze.

Some info:
Disk space: 20GB 
Processor: AMD Sempron(tm) Processor 2500+
Memory: 1.9 GiB
Available disk space: 9.4 GiB

Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit

I don't have any pictures nor documents inside, 3.1 GB of music, and Wine.

I hope I gave enough information, and I thank you for helping me with all my trouble.

Comment: what graphics card are you using?

Comment: [Similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware). Xubuntu 12.04 is more suitable for old hardware, and you should definitely add the graphics specs.

Answer (score 0):

Update the graphics card driver ... maybe upgrade the Ubuntu version.

I underline mikewhatever´s answer...try out xubuntu..its great.

Edit: Lubuntu is also good for older or less capable hardware.